# Django: For each loop with counter that loads queryset in small sets

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am building an online store that displays cards containing products passed into the template as a queryset. The list of products will get large so I want to implement an incremental load that starts with 10 products and there is a button to load 10 more... and that would continue until eventually all the products are displayed. I currently have a for each loop in the template and I was wondering what the best approach would be to add some sort of counting mechanism into the loop so that I am able to achieve the incremental load.

Any idea how I can do this?

views.py

```
def products_page_all(request):
    resetDefaultFilters()
    products = Product.objects.order_by('?')
    args = {
        'products': products,
    }
    return render(request, 'store/products-page.html', args)
```

products-page.html

```
...
{% for product in products %} <-- I want this to only iterate for 10 products at a time
<a href="{% url 'store-view-item' product.product_id %}">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-4 my-auto">
        <div class="card h-100 rounded-0 border-0">
            <div class="img-wrapper">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="{{ product.product_image.url }}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body text-center">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                    <a id="product-name">{{ product.product_name }}</a>
                </h4>
                <p id="seller-name">// {{product.seller.seller_listing_name }} //</p>
                <p class="card-text" id="product-description">{{ product.description_short }}</p>
                <h5 id="product-price">${{ product.price | floatformat:2 }}</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
{% endfor %}
<button>LOAD MORE</button> <-- this button should load the next 10 products
```

Comment: I think you can use Django pagination for this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/

Answer (score 0):

- In order to find the "next 10", you'll either need the products in some fixed order, or explicitly exclude the products that you've already shown.
- You can use `[:10]` or `[0:10]` to get the first ten products, `[10:20]` to get the next ten, and so on.

Something like either (a):

```
    products = (
        Product.objects
        .order_by('id')
        [start : start + 10]
    )
```

Or, (b):

```
    products = (
        Product.objects
        .exclude(id__in=already_shown)
        .order_by('?')
        [:10]
    )
```

The button will need to make an AJAX call to retrieve the next set of products, keeping track of either the `start` or the `already_shown` variables.